# Exponential Growth rate of population

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-distribution, exponential-sum, iterated-integrals, related-rates

The population of an area is $3500$ lacs with the annual growth rate of $2%$ at $t=0$. After this, the population stabilizes at $14000$ lacs. How much time will it take for the population to reach $7000$ lacs?
The options provided are:
 A. $41.2$ Years
  B. $35$ Years 
 C. $5$ Years 
  D. $17.9$ Years.

I have used the exponential growth formula i.e. $P = A.(1+r)^t$, taking $P = 7000$ and $A = 3500$ and got the answer $35$ Years. By using the rule of $70$ also, we will get the same answer as $35$ Years. However, the answer is given as $41.2$ Years, so am I doing it correctly or this initial point and the final point has got to do something with it?

Comment: Indeed, with the "unlimited growth" model that you used, the answer would be $35$ years. But I have a hunch that the problem aims at using a different model, whereby the growth is not unlimited. There should be some limiting term ... Maybe try to find a model like that? Maybe something among these lines : https://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/mordifeqs/logistic.html

Comment: Suggestion: Use the logistic growth model which incorporates a carrying capacity. Your answer should work out then.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the limited growth, i.e. population stabilizes at 14000 lacs, you should consider the [logistic growth model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function): the ODE is
$$x'(t)=Cx(t)(14000-x(t))$$
with  $x(0)=3500$ and $x'(0)/x(0)=0.02$.

Then $C=1/52500$ and, by separation of variables, the solution is
$$x(t)=\frac{14000}{1+3\exp(-2x/75)}.$$
Finally, by solving $x(t)=7000$ we find $t=75\ln(3)/2\approx 41.2$